# Bluetooth keyboards for Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth

Why don't some bluetooth (bt) keyboard work with Linux/ Ubuntu/ Xubuntu?

I have checked around these bt keyboards below and their sellers/ manufacturers has said that thier products only work with Windows/ Android/ Apple, etc. But none of them can tell me that their product can work for Linux.

Do I have to look for a specific Linux supported bt keyboard then - they are extremely rare!

[Microsoft Universal Foldable Keyboard for iPad, iPhone, Android devices, and Windows tablets](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-gb/products/keyboards/universal-foldable-keyboard/gu5-00005)

[Collen Ultra Thin Universal 7 Colors Backlight Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K1BWA7S):

> "Sorry, it can not work with Linux. only for android system, ios
>   system, windows system."

[MoKo Universal Foldable Keyboard, Ultra-Thin Portable Wireless Bluetooth Keyboard for iPad, iPhone, Compatible with iOS, Android and Windows Tablet Devices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EHSLFAY):

> 'It works on windows, mac osx, android & ios. Not sure about linux'

Do they really don't work for Linux or maybe the sellers/ manufacturers never bother to test it?

Do anyone use any of these bt keyboards on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sellers or manufacturers just don't care if their product works with Linux, because they don't perceive Linux as having enough market share to be interesting, so you won't see Linux mentioned in the list of supported operating systems.

That said, in many cases the device works fine with Linux, especially if the interface is based on established standards.

Googling a bit (e.g. "[microsoft universal folded keyboard linux](https://www.google.de/search?q=microsoft+universal+folded+keyboard+linux)") will often [find](http://www.wolfgang-ziegler.com/blog/making-a-microsoft-universal-mobile-keyboard-work-on-raspberrypi-and-linux) information that shows you if it works with linux (or doesn't).

Depending on what country you live in, it's also often possible to just buy the item, try it out, and return it if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `Many sellers or manufacturers just don't care if their product works with Linux, because they don't perceive Linux as having enough market share to be interesting, so you won't see Linux mentioned in the list of supported operating systems.` - that's what I have thought as well!